# force close when onClicklistener set for spinner

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

When I set my onCLick listener in my fragment for the spinner, I get this force close:

```
05-15 16:28:59.266  11419-11419/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41576d40)
05-15 16:28:59.356  11419-11419/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro, PID: 11419
    java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.
            at android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemClickListener(Spinner.java)
            at com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro.BreweryPage2.onCreateView(BreweryPage2.java:57)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1097)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1895)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1514)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:958)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My fragments looks like this:

```
public class BreweryPage2 extends Fragment {

    public BreweryPage2(){}

    String breweryId = "";
    SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.brewery_page, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);


        //get user information
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        final String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

       //todo: get brewery id from shared preferences
        final String breweryId = prefs.getString("breweryID", null);

        //set spinner up
        final Spinner visitedBrewery = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.visitSpinner);

        //set spinner onCLick
        visitedBrewery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
                String choice = visitedBrewery.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if (choice.equals("yes")){
                    //add to database
                    //construct url
                    String url = "myURL";

                    //async task to get beer taste tag percents
                    new AddBreweryVisit(getActivity() ).execute(url);

                }

                else{
                    //delete from database
                    String url = "myURL2";

                    //async task to get beer taste tag percents
                    new KillBreweryVisit(getActivity() ).execute(url);

                }




            }
        });



        //construct url
        String url = "myURL3";

        Log.d("visit" , url);

        //async task to get beer taste tag percents
        new GetBreweryDataJSON(getActivity() , visitedBrewery).execute(url);



        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Line 57 is this line:

```
    visitedBrewery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
```

Comment: Add a View.OnClickListener to your spinner, not an AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

Comment: The fragment layout doesn't seem to contain `visitSpinner`

Comment: I agree with rekaszeru.

Comment: @AndrewQ I tried it but it wants me to declare some abstract info:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2779965c3c35cdb4474f

Answer (score 0):

It'll probably just be easier to put..

```
   visitedBrewery.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

And then let BreweryPage2 implement it.

There might be an easier way but it's what i tend to do and i haven't had any problems yet

Comment: like this? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fa58fa0628b87b2e3960

cause that didnt work

Comment: If you put "visitedBrewery.setOnItemClickListener(this);" and the right click it, go to the bottom of the list then let the it implement it, then right click on "BreweryPage2" and add unimplemented methods then do what you need to do

Comment: You can implement the necessary methods by hand as well. You need your class to implement OnClickListener, and add a method : public void onClick(View view) {...}

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this example . such as

File : res/values/strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">MyAndroidApp</string>
    <string name="country_prompt">Choose a country</string>

    <string-array name="country_arrays">
        <item>Malaysia</item>
        <item>United States</item>
        <item>Indonesia</item>
        <item>France</item>
        <item>Italy</item>
        <item>Singapore</item>
        <item>New Zealand</item>
        <item>India</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

File : res/layout/main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MyAndroidAppActivity.java. codes below

```
public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

  private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
  private Button btnSubmit;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addItemsOnSpinner2();
    addListenerOnButton();
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
  }

  // add items into spinner dynamically
  public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("list 1");
    list.add("list 2");
    list.add("list 3");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
  }

  public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
  }

  // get the selected dropdown list value
  public void addListenerOnButton() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
        "OnClickListener : " + 
                "\nSpinner 1 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) + 
                "\nSpinner 2 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

    });
  }
}
```

and File : CustomOnItemSelectedListener.java

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), 
        "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

}
```

[Reference] [Android spinner (drop down list) example][1](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/)

actually became setOnItemSelectedListener instead of setOnItemClickListener.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

**If you will return True then the dropdown items of the spinner will not be displayed on clicking the Spinner.**